# I've added things into my ArrayList but still not working for loop, and function

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, null

So I have to create a movie kiosk rental system for one of my assignments, and I have to add five films into the database. I have done that properly (I believe) but when I implement the removeMovie() function it is returning null, especially. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Catalogue {


private Kiosk kiosk;
private List<Movie> moviesAvailable = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private List<Movie> moviesRented = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();


public Catalogue(Kiosk kiosk) {
    this.kiosk = kiosk;
    genres.add(new Genre ("SciFi"));
    genres.add(new Genre("Drama"));
    genres.add(new Genre("Crime"));
    moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Matrix", 1999, genres.get(0), 3));
    moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Titanic", 1997, genres.get(1), 4));
    moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("The Silence of the Lambs", 1991, genres.get(2), 3));
    moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Jurassic Park", 1993, genres.get(0), 4));
    moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Terminator 2", 1991, genres.get(0), 3));
}






/**
 *
 */
public void use() {
    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'R') {
        switch (choice){
            case '1': dispMovies(); break;
            case '2': dispAvail(); break;
            case '3': dispGenres(); break;
            case '4': dispMoviegen(); break;
            case '5': dispMovieyear(); break;
            case '6': rentMovie(); break;
            case '7': returnMovie(); break;
        }
    }
}

private char readChoice() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Catalogue! Please make a selection from the menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Display all movies.");
    System.out.println("2. Display all available movies.");
    System.out.println("3. Display all genres.");
    System.out.println("4. Display movies in a genre.");
    System.out.println("5. Display all movies by year.");
    System.out.println("6. Rent a movie.");
    System.out.println("7. Return a movie.");
    System.out.println("R. Return to previous menu.");
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    return In.nextChar();
}

 private void dispMovies(){

}

private void dispAvail(){
}

private void dispGenres(){
}

private void dispMoviegen(){
}

private void dispMovieyear(){
}

private void rentMovie() {
}

private void returnMovie() {
}




private String readTitle() {
    System.out.print("Enter the title of the movie: ");
    return In.nextLine();
}

private int readYear() {
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    return In.nextInt();    
}

/**
 *
 */
public void useAdmin() {
    char choice;
    while((choice = readChoiceadmin()) != 'R') {
        switch (choice) {
            case '1': listCustomers(); break;
            case '2': addCustomer(); break;
            case '3': removeCustomer(); break;
            case '4': listMovies(); break;
            case '5': addMovie(); break;
            case '6': removeMovie(); break;
        }
    }
}

private char readChoiceadmin(){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the administration menu:");
    System.out.println("1. List all customers.");
    System.out.println("2. Add a customer.");
    System.out.println("3. Remove a customer.");
    System.out.println("4. List all movies.");
    System.out.println("5. Add a movie to the catalogue.");
    System.out.println("6. Remove a movie from the catalogue.");
    System.out.println("R. Return to the previous menu.");
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    return In.nextChar();
}

private void listCustomers(){
}

private void addCustomer(){
}

private void removeCustomer(){
}

private void listMovies(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The Kiosk has the following movies:");
    System.out.println(moviesAvailable);
    System.out.println("");
}

private void addMovie(){
}

private void removeMovie(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Removing a movie.");
    String title = readTitle();
    int year = readYear();
    Movie movie = movie(title, year);
    if(movie != null) {
        moviesAvailable.remove(movie);
   System.out.println(movie + " removed from catalogue.");
    }
   else
    System.out.println("No such movie.");




}

    private Movie movie(String title, int year) {

        for (Movie movie : moviesAvailable)
            if(movie.hasTitle(title) && movie.hasYear(year))
                return movie;
        return null;
    }

 Catalogue() {
     //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `hasTitle` and `hasYear` methods?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: public boolean hasTitle(String title) {
        return title.equals(this.title);
    }
    
    
    
        public boolean hasYear(int year) {
       return year == (this.year); 
    }

Comment: What movie name and year did you enter in the console?

Comment: Movie: Matrix, Year: 1999

Comment: Is the `movie(title, year);` returning null or `moviesAvailable.remove(movie);` is not removing it?

Comment: For the remove to work properly you need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods for your Movie class

Comment: It's returning null :/ When I implement my listMovies() it returns "[ ]".

Comment: You need to call this constructor `Catalogue(Kiosk kiosk)` and not the default one as adding movies to `moviesAvailable` happens here

Answer (score 0):

`Movie movie = movie(title, year);`

I don't really understand this.  It looks like a constructor but apparently isn't???

Regardless it smells to me like you are creating a new movie object and then trying to remove that object from your collection.  Which of course it isn't in your collection.  It may be another object with the exact same attributes.  But that doesn't make it the same object that is stored in the collection.

I suggest you read up on Object.equals.  Then use forEach to loop over your collection.  Probably something like

```
String title = readTitle();
int year = readYear();
Movie searchMovie = new Movie(title, year);    
for (Movie movie : moviesAvailable) {
    if (movie.equals(searchMovie) {
       moviesAvailable.remove(movie)
    }
}
```